# How to check LDAP connection against Novell?

Tags: ldap, novell

I would like to check if the connection to the Novell via LDAP is ok, how can I do it ? (I know that one can use LDP.exe to check a connection to Active Directory for instance)

Answer (score 0):

Any LDAP tool will work of course.  Just try to bind and see if it succeeds.  Perhaps query for some object that will always be there as your test.